# Can't set style for path in resource dictionary

Tags: silverlight-4.0, resourcedictionary

I am not able to set path of resource dictionary....

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary  Source="/SilverlightOrganization;component/Styles/BlueStyles.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I also tried it ...

```
   <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary  Source="Styles/BlueStyles.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

What can be issue help please....

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to add a key to your ResourceDictionary tag:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="ucRescDict">
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/PDMC;component/Views/XamlResources/AppFormsStyle.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
    <converters:InvertBooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="invertBoolToVisibility" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```